# Is there a cleaner way for File::Find to return a list of wanted files?

Tags: perl, file-find

I find the design choice behind [`File::Find::find`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFind) a little surprising. The examples I've come across all show `find` used in void context.

The [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aFind#The-wanted-function) also clarifies that the `\&wanted` coderef in `find( \&wanted, @dirs )` is not meant to be a filter (emphasis my own):

> The `wanted()` function does whatever verifications you want on ***each***
>   file and directory. Note that despite its name, the `wanted()`
>   function is a generic callback function, and does ***not*** tell
>   `File::Find` if a file is "wanted" or not. In fact, its return value
>   is ignored.

---

But what if I do want to use it as a filter in a manner similar to [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html)? I'm curious to know if there's another way to write the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use File::Find;

my $wanted = qr/^\d{2}_/;  # e.g.

my @wanted;
find( sub { -f && /$wanted/ && push @wanted, $_ }, '.' );

# I wish my @wanted = find( ... ); worked

say for @wanted;
```

Comment: Before anyone suggests using `glob` or `readdir`, the reason why I want to use `File::Find::find` is because of its ability to recurse into directories.

Comment: I think you current code is perfectly fine. Why do you need an alternative? I probably would rephrase you \&wanted coderef, but nothing relly different.

Comment: @pmakholm : I know the code doesn't have an issue... but it seems cumbersome to have to accumulate results inside `\&wanted` and I wanted to know if there was a function or alternative syntax that allowed me to generate the filtered list for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking on CPAN, I find several alternative interfaces to File::Find available that aim to simplify the interface.

I would try [`File::Finder`](http://search.cpan.org/~merlyn/File-Finder-0.53/lib/File/Finder.pm), by well-known Perl expert Randal Schwartz, first.

[`File::Find::Rule`](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.33/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm) is another one.

*(It is probably safe to say that, if people are writing modules to do this, there is no easy built-in way to do it.)*

Comment: Hmmm... I didn't think that I'd have to look beyond `File::Find` for this kind of functionality. I like your suggested alternatives though, especially `File::Find::Rule`

Comment: `File::Finder` has all the functionality of `File::Find::Rule` (you can even use FFR plugins with it!) and more.  I wrote `File::Finder` because I could not remember FFR's naming convention... mine follows `find(1)` precisely.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're using it in the right way. The only things you can do is to wrap the `find` function inside another one that creates the array (with `push`) and then return it.

```
sub find_to_array {
    my $wanted = shift;
    my @array;
    find( sub { -f && /$wanted/ && push @array, $_ }, '.' );
    return @array;
}
```

In this way you can have what you were looking for, but it's almost the same as you have done.