# How to put parameters into finds "wanted function" and get a return

Tags: perl

I am rather new to perl.
I have a find function to travers a directory structure which has a "wanted function" which is called for each found file.

I want to put in parameters into that "wanted function" and get back a return value.

I solved that with global variables and it works, but I don´t like the code ;-)

```
$param1 = "value";
$param2 = "value2";
find(\&wantedFunction , $directory);
print $returnValue;

sub wantedFunction
{ #do something with $param1 and $param2
  $returnValue = f1($param1);";
}
```

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: I assume you're talking about [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html#The-wanted-function)?

Comment: Also, please explain what `$param1`, `$param2`, and the return value are supposed to represent. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to control the wantedFunction with parameters. For Example I want to calculate the minimal LEvenstein Distance for a given file, this file wold be an input parameter, the output would be the actual minimum Levenshtein Distanance and the corresponding found file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People have [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12620423/176646) about returning values from `File::Find::find` before; it's easy enough to use an anonymous subroutine or a closure as [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30535750/176646) and [Sobrique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30536590/176646) described, but another common suggestion is to use a module like [`File::Finder`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Finder), which I think has a slightly cleaner interface.

The following creates a hash of paths inside `/tmp` to their corresponding Levenshtein distance from a fixed string:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dump;
use File::Find;
use File::Finder;
use Text::Levenshtein qw(distance);

my $start = '/tmp/foo';

my %distances = File::Finder->collect(
    sub { $File::Find::name => distance($start, $File::Find::name) },
    '/tmp'
);

dd \%distances;
```

#### Output:

```
{ 
  "/tmp" => 4,
  "/tmp/fie" => 2,
  "/tmp/foe" => 1,
  "/tmp/foo" => 0,
  "/tmp/fum" => 2,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bear in mind that when you're calling a sub repeatedly with `File::Find` then there will be multiple return codes. I'm not sure if you can easily "capture" that return code in the conventional sense. You could, however, pass in an array (or scope one) that holds the results.

The general idiom for passing parameters *into* a callback sub (such as in `File::Find` or `XML::Twig`) is to wrap it in an anonymous sub - passing the arguments through. (Normally, theses are in `@_`, but File::Find uses `$_` to pass the path to the callback.)

E.g.

```
sub wanted {
    my ( $param1, $param2, $path ) = @_;
}

find ( sub { wanted ( "first", "second", $_ ) }, "/path/to/find";
```

This way you create a mini anonymous subroutine (with no name) that just calls `wanted` with some extra parameters.

For capturing the results - there's a variety of answers. Personally I think the simplest is a results array or hash (depending on exactly what you're trying to accomplish) that you update within your `wanted` sub.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
my ($param1, $param2, @found);
sub wanted {
   push @found, $_
      if is_within_lev_dist($_, $param1, $param2);
}

@found = ();
($param1, $param2) = (..., ...);
find(\&wanted, $dir);
say for @found;
```

But that's suffers from [tight coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29). I far prefer the following:

```
my @found;
find(sub {
   push @found, $_
      if is_within_lev_dist($_, $param1, $param2)
}, $dir);
say for @found;
```

---

`is_within_lev_dist` would look like

```
sub is_within_lev_dist {
   my ($path, $param1, $param2) = @_;
   ...
   return $true_or_false;
}
```

Comment: Tnx: could you please explain what sub { push @found, wanted() } is syntactically

Comment: `sub foo { ... }` is basically `*foo = sub { ... }`, and when you do `\&foo`, you get the value `sub` returned. I simply skipped giving the sub a name.

Comment: `sub {...}` defines an anonymous sub and returns a reference to it, just like `[...]` or `{...}` define anonymous arrays and hashes and return references to them

Comment: Aren´t ($param1, $param2, @found) kind of "global" in that file?

Comment: In the first snippet, yeah, which is part of why it's bad and why I recommended against it